# How can I make wp_nav_menu() support <br> tags?

Tags: menus, walker

Static webpage created nav menu separating titles using `<br>` tags, but
when I'm converting the site into WordPress I'm missing `<br>` tags there.

How can I enable using `<br>` tags in `wp_nav_menu()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap menu link texts in html tags, in example `Menu <span>Item</span>`. Now you can create line break with CSS.

```
.nav span {
    display: block;
}
```